# How to split and separate time stamp from a string in R

Tags: r

I have a string and need to separate time stamp from that string. I used`strsplit`function for string splitting. Attaching my code here.

```
string <- "10:00:in(XXXX),10:47:out(XXXX),12:36:in(XXXX),13:12:out(XXXX)"
splt <- strsplit(string,split = ",")[[1]]
> splt
[1] "10:00:in(XXXX)"  "10:47:out(XXXX)" "12:36:in(XXXX)"  "13:12:out(XXXX)"
```

Following is my expected output,

```
[1] "10:00"  "10:47" "12:36"  "13:12"
```

What modification should I need to add in`strsplit`function. Can you help me to figure out this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can `substr` if they always occur in the first part of the string. Something like `substr(splt, 1, 5)`

Comment: try `gsub(".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*","\\1",strsplit(string,split = ",")[[1]])`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you could add to `strsplit` but you could wrap it in a `substr` call and as your times are a standard length this will work.

```
string <- "10:00:in(XXXX),10:47:out(XXXX),12:36:in(XXXX),13:12:out(XXXX)"
splt <- substr(strsplit(string,split = ",")[[1]], 1, 5)
splt
[1] "10:00" "10:47" "12:36" "13:12"
```